# documentation for Math Function -> XYZ Math Surface

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, mathematics

I struggled to find any documentation on the definition of math functions for the module XYZ math Surface.
For example how is the "Tan inverse" written?

Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find the script https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Extensions:2.5/Py/Scripts/Add_Mesh/Add_3d_Function_Surface/
https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-extensions/trunk/py/scripts/addons/add_mesh_extra_objects/

Comment: @FFeller: thanks! Looks like the math definitions are in the safe_list in linked script.,